# python regex for single or multiple empty endline

Tags: python, regex

I know there will be easier way to do this, for example using `endswith` or even `str.split('\n')`. But I want to know how to use regex to find out if a text file has one/multiple/None empty lines at the end.

suppose I got the content by using `content = f_obj.read()`

I tried:

```
one_N = r'\S(\s{1})$'
multi_N = r'\S\s(\s+)$'
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Empty Line: `(?<!\n)\Z`  - [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zpa1Va/2)

One Empty Line: `(?<=(?<!\n)\n)\Z` - [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xlnuif/1)

More than one Empty Line: `\n{2,}\Z` - [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nbE0gc/1)

Answer (score 1):

The regex solution to check for empty lines is below

```
if (line.matches("\\s*")) {
   print('Line is blank')
}
```